# Azure PowerBI Workspace - Export Report

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-powershell

We have some reports in a workspace on Azure. They were imported as pbix files by somebody else via the [github console app](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/power-bi-embedded-integrate-report-into-web-app). Is there a way to retrieve them back from the azure workspace(not just get list but "export" them)?

I tried Azure cli and could not find a command for that.